# Center an image in document

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing

Not even really sure what kind of title this question needs. Basically I have made a cheeky bit of JavaScript in jsFiddle and it works perfectly. Then I've popped on a test site and it doesn't work at all. I cannot figure out why at all and it's doing my head in.

Basically the code calculates the width of the image and uses this value to place the image in the center of the page. Works great on the window.resize but for some reason the document.load isn't working on the test server but it works fine in JS Lint. I've popped an alert in there as well for testing purposes.

jsFiddle Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/sambeckhamdesign/4g4nD/49/

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons, but just out of interest wouldn't it be easier to centre the image using css?

Comment: The image changes size based on the size of the browser window and it needs to be positioned absolutely so I need to position it `left:50%;` then make the left margin half the width.

Comment: I noticed you've got it working now :P

Comment: I do yeah. Bit of a schoolboy error on my part there. Still have to wait 3 minutes before I can mark this embarrassment of a question as answered :(

Comment: Renamed to something related to the question instead of text-messaging speak...

Comment: still... if you did `margin: 0 auto` on the image and `text-align: center` on the image it wouldn't make any difference how big the image is, it'll always be centered. :)

Comment: Yes but it needs to be positioned absolutely because of a CSS3 animation. Have a look at the link to see what I mean.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Load jQuery *before* your script and use your browser's error console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined java.js:9
```

Comment: Can't believe I did this. Feel a bit silly now. Ta

Answer (score 1):

You've put your javascript method above the call to include jQuery.

At that point, jQuery hasn't been defined. Switch the lines so that jQuery is first.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_js/java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
<script src="/_js/java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it should be

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_js/java.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```